# Is commons-lang3 3.4 backward compatible respect to 3.1

Tags: hapi-fhir, apache-commons-lang3

I have a maven project with many dependencies, two of them `primefaces-extensions` and `hapi-fhir-base`, both of them needs `commons-lang3`, but primefaces declares version 3.1 as dependency, but hapi needs >= 3.2. Is safe to assume that commons-lang3 3.4 will be fine for primefaces if it declares 3.1 as dependency version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [release notes](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/release-notes/RELEASE-NOTES-3.4.txt):

For 3.4 compatibility to 3.3.x:

> Commons Lang 3.4 is fully binary compatible to the last release and
>   can  therefore be used as a drop in replacement for 3.3.2.

For 3.3.x to 3.1:

> This release introduces backwards incompatible changes in 
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat:
>
> Method 'protected java.util.List parsePattern()' has been removed
>
> Method 'protected java.lang.String parseToken(java.lang.String, int[])' has   been removed
>
> Method 'protected org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat$NumberRule. selectNumberRule(int, int)' has been removed
>
> These changes were the result of [LANG-462]. It is assumed that this
>   change  will not break clients

So it should work, as long as the changes in FastDateFormat are not breaking your code, which the developers think should not be possible.